# IIS7 Url Rewrite Module gives an error when trying to configure rewrite rules

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-6, asp.net, iis-7.5

When clicking on the Url Rewrite feature in the IIS7 Manager I get an error:

```
There was an error while performing this operation.

Details:

Filename: \\?\C:\Domains\...<blah_blah>...\web.config
Error: The configuration section 'system.webServer/rewrite/rules'
cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration
```

I just moved from a IIS6 setup to a IIS7 server and my web.config file does not have a rewrite section under system.webServer

Answer (score 1):

IIS6 and IIS7 use distinct parts of the `web.config` file in order to specify site configuration.

For example, IIS6 uses the `system.web` section, whereas IIS7 uses the `system.webServer` section. But, it's not so simple as changing that one element because the underlying children are also different.

Some key changes:

- `<httpModules>` and `<httpHandlers>` have been renamed to `<modules>` and `<handlers>`, respectively.
- Each handler in IIS7 requires a name attribute. If you don't specify it, you'll get an error message.
- The handlers node has an optional, but good-to-define `accessPolicy` attribute. This value depends on your handlers, so use the ones that are right for you.

These suggestions and more information can be found in this posting: [Use a Single Web.Config for IIS6 and IIS7](http://arcware.net/use-a-single-web-config-for-iis6-and-iis7/)